# Call External REST API from Button with Classic SFDC

Tags: rest-api, rest

I am looking to call an external REST API when a user clicks on a button in Salesforce classic. After some research I found I can use the javascript below and the content of sforce.connection.remoteFunction gets executed. This works fine to fetch an Auth Token. However this is just the first step, and I then need to call the REST API a second time in the function runBot(). How can I also trigger a second call to the API with just one button?

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open( "GET", "/soap/ajax/11.0/connection.js", false); 
xhr.send(); 
eval(xhr.responseText); 

function runBot(token){
    alert('My token is ' + token);
    alert('The case is ' + {!case.Id});
}

sforce.connection.remoteFunction(
{ 
    url : 'https://myCloudApp/v1/authentication',
    method: "POST",    
    requestData: '{"username": "my.username", "password": "Password1" }',
    requestHeaders: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, 
    onSuccess : function(response) { 
        alert('success'); 
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        token = obj.token;
        result = runBot(token);
    }, 
    onFailure : function(response) { 
        alert('Failed ' + response); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I just realised the reference to sforce.connection.remoteFunction is simply a call to a built-in function...which I can do as many times as I like. So altering the code as follows works fine:

```
onSuccess : function(response) { 
     alert('success'); 
     var obj = JSON.parse(response);
     token = obj.token;

     //second call to external API
     //----------------------------------------------
     sforce.connection.remoteFunction(
     { 
       ...details of REST call
     }, 
}
```